# time format for Start date, End date - SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In my SSRS report i have Startdate, enddate parameters(datetime).For start date I have default value as `=DateAdd("d",-7,Now())` and end date as `=Now()`. While select startdate from datepicker, I want to display time format `"00:00:00"` and for end date `"23:59:59"`. How can we achieve this with ssrs function?
Can anyone help me to complete this?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What are you saying is not clear. Do you want 24 Hr time format ?

Comment: yes.. while selecting date from datepicker need time for start date as "00:00:00" and for enddate datepicker is "23:59:59"

Comment: Ok so you want static values for time in start date and end date right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the format for start date and end date as following :

```
=DateAdd("d",-7,(CDate(Format(Today(), "yyyy-MM-dd" & " 00:00:01"))))
=CDate(Format(Today(), "yyyy-MM-dd" & " 23:59:59"))
```

Now, I am able to get the startdate as "00:00:01 AM" and enddate as "23:59:59"